# Iterate over an Object and display data in 4 different divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento-1.9, php-5.5

I have an object which has multiple objects, kind of like an array of an array.

I need to iterate over it and display a field from the 2nd level array(i.e the array which is inside the main array) in 4 different divs and when the 4th div is filled I need to again display the 5th element in the first div. Kind of like this :-

```
<span class="anchorScroll27j" id="09"></span>
                <h3 class="alphaNew to9" id="09">0 to 9</h3>

                <?php
                    foreach ($categories as $cat) {

                        $categoryName = $cat->getName();
                        if(is_numeric(substr($categoryName, 0, 1))) { ?>                            

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <ul class="designer-listing">
                                        <li><a href="<?php echo $cat->getUrl();?>"><?php echo $categoryName;?></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <ul class="designer-listing">
                                        <li><a href="<?php echo $cat->getUrl();?>"><?php echo $categoryName;?></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <ul class="designer-listing">
                                        <li><a href="<?php echo $cat->getUrl();?>"><?php echo $categoryName;?></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <ul class="designer-listing">
                                        <li><a href="<?php echo $cat->getUrl();?>"><?php echo $categoryName;?></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                    }
                ?>


            <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

This is what I get in $categories :-

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 819
        [entity_type_id] => 3
        [attribute_set_id] => 3
        [parent_id] => 4
        [created_at] => 2015-02-19 10:16:51
        [updated_at] => 2015-02-19 10:16:51
        [path] => 1/2/4/819
        [position] => 288
        [level] => 3
        [children_count] => 0
        [is_active] => 1
        [name] => categoryName
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 1333
        [entity_type_id] => 3
        [attribute_set_id] => 3
        [parent_id] => 4
        [created_at] => 2016-04-12 17:52:30
        [updated_at] => 2017-12-04 12:13:44
        [path] => 1/2/4/1333
        [position] => 429
        [level] => 3
        [children_count] => 0
        [is_active] => 1
        [name] => catNAme2
    )
```

But the problem here is that when the 5th element comes it gets displayed below the 1st div but as a seperate div. But i want the 5th element in the same div as the 1st one, the 6th element in the same one as 2nd one as so on.
How do i go about this?

I have raked my brains but to no avail. I am a newbie in html and css and this is my first day doing this.

Comment: you need to add in the 4 divs you shown here, and data in the sequence, 1st 2nd 3rd 4th 1st 2nd 3rd 4th so on in divs

Comment: @AhmedSunny i know that but how to do it. like what will be the code for it. I know the logic for it but don't know how to write the code for it. If i do it in the way i mentioned in the code above it creates different divs for each element. the sixth element is not displayed as the 1st element in the 2nd row.

Comment: can you show what you are getting in categories  , just dummy data

Comment: @AhmedSunny I have displayed the data in $categories like this i get multiple object in $ categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a counter, and check in each iteration
and use the following way,

if you loop through the divs then it will make divs again in each iteration.

```
<?php
$key = 1;
foreach ($categories as $cat) {

if ($key === 5)
    $key = 1;

if ($key === 1) {
    $div1 = $div1 . '<li><a href="' . $cat->getUrl() . '">' . $cat->getName() . '</a></li>';
} else if ($key === 2) {
    $div2 = $div2 . '<li><a href="' . $cat->getUrl() . '">' . $cat->getName() . '</a></li>';
} else if ($key === 3) {
    $div3 = $div3 . '<li><a href="' . $cat->getUrl() . '">' . $cat->getName() . '</a></li>';
} else if ($key === 4) {
    $div4 = $div4 . '<li><a href="' . $cat->getUrl() . '">' . $cat->getName() . '</a></li>';
}
$key++;
}
?>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <ul class="designer-listing">
        <?php echo $div1; ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <ul class="designer-listing">
        <?php echo $div2; ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <ul class="designer-listing">
        <?php echo $div3; ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <ul class="designer-listing">
        <?php echo $div4; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```